# Where can I find I/O address range of BIOS?

Tags: memory-address, bios, datasheet, chipset, memory-mapped-io

I have been reading [this](https://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/datasheets/7-series-chipset-pch-datasheet.pdf) chipset datasheet for a while, looking for the BIOS I/O address range, but I haven't found it.

Where can I find the BIOS address range? Is it on this datashhet or should I look in other place?

Comment: BIOS is a chip containing machine instructions.  Why would it have I/O addresses?

Comment: @RobertHarvey Right. In some context, not even chip, just a piece of software